# How to show that it is an invariant set?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this system of differential equations:

$$\frac {dx}{dt} = x\left(1-\frac x5\right)- \frac 25xy $$

$$\frac {dy}{dt} = y\left(1-\frac y5\right)- \frac 35xy $$

I have found the equilibria for the system. 
Now, I have to show that that

$$ L = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: y = 2x, x \gt 0\} $$

I have no idea how to show that this is an invariant set. Could someone give me a hint on how to start the the proof?

Comment: Just for clarification for myself as a non-expert, what do you mean this is an invariant set? invariant under what? Do you mean any function that satisfies those two equations keeps this set invariant?

Comment: I mean that, for any initial condition in the set L, the solution to the system of differential equations remains in the set L for all time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to show that the function $V(x,y)=2x-y$ is constant along the trajectories whose points are contained in $L$. Consider the derivative
$$
\dot V=\frac{dV(x(t),y(t))}{dt}=
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{dt}+
\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dt}=
2x\left(1-\frac x5\right)- \frac 45xy-y\left(1-\frac y5\right)+ \frac 35xy 
$$
$$
=2x-\frac25x^2-\frac15xy-y+\frac15y^2
$$
Now we can show that
$$
\left.\dot V\right|_{(x,y)\in L}=\left.\dot V\right|_{y=2x}=
2x-\frac25x^2-\frac25x^2-2x+\frac45x^2=0.
$$
This implies that the solution of the initial value problem with the initial conditions $x(t_0)=x_0$, $y(t_0)=y_0$ satisfying $V(x_0,y_0)=2x_0-y_0=0$ stays in L for all $t\ge t_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand !